# Show that is $\sigma(X',X)-$closed in $X'$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ a banach space and $K:X\to\mathcal{P}(X')$ the map such that $$K(x)=\{x'\in X':\langle x',x\rangle=\| x\|^2, \| x'\|=\|x\|\}$$

Show that for each $x\in X$, $K(x)$ is $\sigma(X',X)-$closed in $X'$; And if $X$ is a Hilbert space, then $\mbox{card}(K(x))=1$ for each $x\in X$.

First of all, I tried to prove that $K(x)$ is not empty, convex and $K(\alpha x)=\alpha K(x)$ for each $x\in X$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.

On the other hand, I know that if we have two orthonormal families and these are the basis of some Hilbert Space, then they have the same cardinality. So, I need find an orthonormal basis for X, but I don't see how.

Can give some hint, thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what does $card  \big( K(X) \big)$ mean?

Answer (score 1):

Let me write $x^{*}$ instead of $x'$ and $x^{*}(x)$ in place of $\langle x',x \rangle$. (I am more familiar with this notation). First let us show that $K(x)$ is closed in weak* topology. Suppose $x_i^{*} \in K$ for each i and $x_i^{*} \to x^{*}$ so that $x_i^{*} (y) \to x^{*} (y)$ for every $y \in X$. We have to show that $x^{*}(x)=||x||^{2}$ and $||x^{*}||=||x||$. We know that $x_i^{*}(x)=||x||^{2}$ and $||x_i^{*}||=||x||$ for each i. Clearly $x^{*}(x)=\lim x_i^{*}(x)=||x||^{2}$. Note that $|x^{*}(y)|=\lim |x_i^{*}(y)| \leq ||x|| ||y||$ so $||x^{*}|| \leq ||x||$. To prove equality just note that $||x^{*}|| \geq \frac {x^{*}(x)} {||x||}=||x||$. This proves the first part. Now suppose X is a Hilbert space and suppose $x^{*} \in K$. By Riesz Theorem on the dual of a Hilbert space ther exists $u \in X$ such that $x^{*}(y)= \langle y,u\rangle$ for all $y$. Now $||u||=||x^{*}||=||x||$ and $\langle x,u\rangle =||x||^{2}$. We have to show that there is a unique vector $u$ satsifying these two conditions. In fact we have $u=x$ necessarily. Just expand $||x-u||^{2}$ as $||u||^{2}+||x||^{2}-2\langle x,u\rangle$ which is $0$.